# How is one implementation of the constant function equal to a version using a lambda?

Tags: function, haskell, lambda

I'm currently revising the chapter for the lambda `(\)` expressions in Haskell.  Was just wondering if someone could please help explain how did this:

```
const :: a → b → a 
const x _ = x (this part)
```

Get defined into this:

```
const :: a → (b → a) 
const x = λ_ → x (how did it become like this?)
```

Comment: Do you understand why the following is true: The `id` function can be defined as `id x = x` but it can also be defined as `id = \x -> x`

Comment: By definition .

Comment: This question is sort of philosophical, really. Definitions are just pairs of things that a bunch of people have agreed to consider the same. The question of "how did X get defined to be Y" is a boring one; somebody announced the definition and other people were on board, and that's it. You get to choose whether you're on board, too, or whether you decide to interpret X to mean some other thing Z. Of course you're going to have a hard time communicating with the "X means Y" community if you do that, but, like, you do you, man!

Answer (score 8):

The signatures `a -> b -> a` and `a -> (b -> a)` are *parsed exactly the same*, much like the arithmetic expressions `1 - 2 - 3` and `(1 - 2) - 3` are the same: the `->` operator is right-associative, whereas the `-` operator is left associative, i.e. the parser effectively puts the parentheses in the right place if not explicitly specified. In other words, `A -> B -> C` is *defined to be* `A -> (B -> C)`.

If we explicitly write `a -> (b -> a)`, then we do this to put focus on the fact that we're dealing with curried functions, i.e. that we can accept the arguments one-by-one instead of all at once, but *all* multi-parameter functions in Haskell are curried anyway.

As for why `const x _ = x` and `const x = \_ -> x` are equivalent: well first, to be pedantic they're *not* equivalent, see bottom of this answer. But let's ignore that for now.

Both lambdas and (single) function clauses are just ways to define functions. Like,

```
sqPl1 :: Int -> Int
sqPl1 x = x^2 + 1
```

does the same as

```
sqPl1 = \x -> x^2 + 1
```

It's just a different syntax. Some would say the `f x = ...` notation is just  syntactic sugar for binding `x` in a lambda, i.e. `f = \x -> ...`, because Haskell is based on lambda calculus and in lambda calculus lambdas are the only way to write functions. (That's a bit of an oversimplification though.)

---

I said they're *not quite* equivalent. I'm referring to two things here:

1. You can have local definitions whose scope outlasts a parameter binding. For example if I write

   ```
   foo x y = ec * y
    where ec = {- expensive computation depending on `x` -}
   ```

   then `ec` will always be computed from scratch whenever `foo` is applied. However, if I write it as

   ```
   foo x = \y -> ec * y
    where ec = {- expensive computation depending on `x` -}
   ```

   then I can *partially apply* `foo` to one argument, and the resulting single-argument function can be evaluated with many different `y` values without needing to compute `ec` again. For example `map (foo 3) [0..90]` would be faster with the lambda definition. (On the flip side, if the stored value takes up a lot of memory it may be preferrable to *not* keep it around; it depends.)
2. Haskell has a notion of [constant applicative forms](https://wiki.haskell.org/Constant_applicative_form). It's a subtle topic that I won't go into here, but that can be affected by whether you write a function as a lambda or with clauses or expand arguments.